# How to swap views using a swipe gesture XCode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, view, swipe

I am using XCode to develop a Cocoa touch application for the iOS platform but have had trouble finding out how to get a swipe gesture implemented that would allow the user to swipe their finger left or right to change to a new `ViewController` (nib/xib file). I have done a `swapView IBAction` using a button and modal transitioning and I have read about Apple's `TouchGestureRecognizer` but I don't know how to implement a swipe action that would allow a view change.

I do NOT want to use a scroll view, as I have several dozen view controllers, that I want the user to be able to swipe through.

Here is an example:

First View Controller.xib:
SwipeRight- Go to second View Controller.xib

Second View Controller.xib:
SwipeLeft- Go to first View Controller.xib
SwipeRight- Go to third View Controller.xib

etc, etc

I have not used UISwipe/Touch Gestures before but I have used an `IBAction` method to switch views using a button with Modal Transitioning (see below):

```
-(IBAction)swapViews; { 
    SecondViewController *second2 =[[SecondViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    second2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:second2 animated:YES];
    [second2 release];
}
```

Is using a swipe to do a similar method formatted differently? If so, how do I sort this out and format it.

Thank You

**Edit - Answer as Per Comment on Question**

Place this in your viewDidLoad

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftDetected:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];
```

Then add a selector as by pasting the following code into your main...

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NC2ViewController *second2 =[[NC2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NC2ViewController" bundle:nil];
    second2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:second2 animated:YES];
    [second2 release];
}
```

Then just make sure you import the otherViewController you are swapping to using

```
#import "SecondViewController"
```

at the top of your main file. Hope this helps.

**End Edit**

Comment: Hi AppleFanBoy, Were you able to implement UIGesture to swap views? I have tried the same approach but have been unsuccessful. The previous NIB does not release. Can you please post code if it is working. Thanks.

Comment: I was successful and could get it to work

Comment: Place this in your viewDidLoad;  {UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = 
  [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self 
               action:@selector(swipeLeftDetected:)];
  swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
  [swipeRecognizer release];
  
 }

Comment: Then add a selector as by pasting the following code into your main...

- (IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
 
 NC2ViewController *second2 =[[NC2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NC2ViewController" bundle:nil];
 second2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
 [self presentModalViewController:second2 animated:YES];
 [second2 release];
 
 
 
}

Comment: Then just make sure you import the otherViewController you are swapping to using #import "SecondViewController" at the top of your main file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for not replying to this in a long time.

Comment: Thanks AppleFanBoy for these tips.  Exactly what I was looking for aswell !

Comment: @AppleFanBoy you can update your question adding the solution. Thank you anyways, it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect time to use [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or, more specifically, [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer).

For more info on how to use them, read up in the [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) section of the Event Handling Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you want to swipe left to bring up another view from the right.

In the storyboard, drag and drop a swipe gesture recognizer. It will make an icon below the view controller; drag this icon and drop onto the ViewController you want to navigate to. This will add a segue, select custom segue. Then create a UIStoryboardSegue class. Add the following code:

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController* source = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController* destination = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

    CGRect sourceFrame = source.view.frame;
    sourceFrame.origin.x = -sourceFrame.size.width;

    CGRect destFrame = destination.view.frame;
    destFrame.origin.x = destination.view.frame.size.width;
    destination.view.frame = destFrame;

    destFrame.origin.x = 0;

    [source.view.superview addSubview:destination.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         source.view.frame = sourceFrame;
                         destination.view.frame = destFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         UIWindow *window = source.view.window;
                         [window setRootViewController:destination];
                     }];
}
```