# swiping content to move to next piece on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Sorry for the super basic question but I'm just looking for a little direction.

I would like my user to be able to swipe his or her finger horizontally in order to get the content to change.

Very much like the iPhone interface works where the user can do a small swipe and see the content match their finger's position.

Can anyone point me in a direction that would get here?

thanks!

Comment: Please read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684099/how-to-swap-views-using-a-swipe-gesture-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the examples for the Page Control. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Or here is an example for scrolling without the page control:
http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/